# Fecha donde no hay registro mostrar 0

Tags: php, mysql, null, sum

quisiera resolver la siguiente duda.

Tengo la siguiente **consulta**:

```
SELECT linea, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y/%m/%d') as fecha, 
sum(ifnull(total, 0)) as TotalAS 
 FROM scrap.registro
 WHERE fecha>= '2020-11-01'  AND fecha<= '2020-11-30' AND linea = 'L-02 (SMT)'
 group by DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Con el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi duda es la siguiente:**

Cual seria la manera de mostrar los dias donde no hubo registros, mostrar el valor 0.

En este ejemplo el **dia 09 de noviembre** si me da el valor 0, pero es por que existe un registro que al sumar o su total es "0" por eso me lo muestra, necesito por ejemplo que el **dia 01 de noviembre** tambien salga el valor 0 pero en ese dia no tengo registros por eso no lo muestra en mi consulta.

**Estructura** de tabla:

```
# id, fecha, turno, linea, responsable, noparte, familia, dpto, fcmanufactura, descripcion, costunit, cantidad, total, categoria, equipo, problema, causa, accion, ingeniero, targetdate, seriall, supervisor, fechaGrafica
'10637', '2020-11-09 14:35:35', '1 (Primero)', 'Caterpillar (Final)', 'Procesos', '28491943', 'Caterpillar', 'Final Assembly for Diesel Products', '2020-11-09', 'COVER-A4E4 - NO ECOAT', '4.08', '7', '28.56', 'Manufacturing', 'N/A', 'SE RETIRO COVER PARA RETRABAJAR PIEZAS', 'RETRABAJO', 'SE MANDO MATERIAL A EQUIPO DE CALIDAD', '-', '2020-11-09', '', 'Mauricio Delgado', '2020-11-01'
```

Grafica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si el registro no existe, de por si no lo podrás mostrar. Lo que deberías hacer, es crear un registro que demuestre que ese dia no hubo nada.

Comment: Cabe recordar, que 0 no es igual a NULL. Asi mismo... un resultado 0, no es lo mismo a que no hayan registros.

Comment: Como bien dice @Excorpion, no se puede mostrar algo que no existe, o lo sumo podrías crearlo, de forma artificial. Quizá la cuestión aquí sería, ¿por qué quieres mostrar algo que realmente no existe en tus datos? ¿No se puede resolver esto de otro modo?

Comment: Si todo tiene logica, falto mencionar que mi informacion la represento en una grafica de highcharts, me interesa saber que ese dia no hubo registros o "dinero" registrado, y llevar el control de esos dias, no se si por parte de highchart pueda resolver eso, actualizo mi post con la grafica.

Comment: La base de datos no tiene nada que ver con eso. Puedes por ejemplo hacer la consulta a la base de datos, traer lo que haya en ella y luego verificar los datos, y agregar las fechas que no estén en el objeto final que usarás para generar el gráfico.

Comment: Podrías hacer algo que en BI se llama dimensión tiempo, es una tabla donde están guardadas las fechas, entonces le haces un left join a dicha tabla uniendo por la fecha, asi tendrias la fecha y el valor que corresponde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostrar todas las fechas del rango y sus totales.

La subconsulta `fechas` crea un rango de fechas y con eso se hace un `right join` de la tabla `registro`  con la subconsulta  `fechas` para mostrar todas las fechas del rango y con valor 0 las fechas que no presentan movimiento.

```
    select  fechas.fecha as fecha, sum(ifnull(total, 0)) as TotalAS 
    from scrap.registro
    right join
     (
        select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) fecha from
             (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
             (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
             (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
             (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
             (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
    ) fechas
    on date(scrap.registro.fecha) = date(fechas.fecha)
    
    where fechas.fecha >= '2020-11-01' and fechas.fecha <= '2020-11-30' 
    and (linea = 'L-02 (SMT)' or linea is null)
    
    group by fechas.fecha
    order by fecha.fecha desc
    ;
```

[Referencia sub consulta fechas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296238/5525964)

Comment: Gracias de nuevo tu respuesta me fue de ayuda